# Get start_date and end_date of the week for every week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my code

```sql
declare @startdate date='2021-01-01'
declare @enddate date='2021-12-31'
declare @week_end_date date

while (@startdate <= @enddate)
begin
    if (datepart(week, @startdate) = 1)
        select '01-01-2021'
    else
        set @startdate = DATEADD(day,1-datepart(dw,@startdate),@startdate)

    select @startdate week_start_date

    if (datepart(week, @startdate) = 53)
        select '2021-12-31' 
    else
        set @week_end_date = dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(dw, @startdate), @startdate)

    select @week_end_date week_end_date

    set @startdate = dateadd(week, 1, @startdate)   
end
```

I want to achieve the following result

```
week_start date             week_end_date
-----------------------------------------
2021-01-01                   2021-01-02
2021-01-03                   2021-01-09
2021-01-10                   2021-01-16
.
.
.
.
.
.
2021-12-26                  2021-12-31
.
.
```

I am trying to get `start_date` and `end_date` of the week for every week, but I want the start date of the first week to be `2020-01-01` and end date of last week 2020-12-31

In both the cases `else` is running.

Comment: I would suggest using a tally or numbers table instead of loops for this. I don't quite understand the desired output. Can you try explaining it?

Comment: @Sean OP wants to create a list of weeks (Sunday to Saturday) spanning the year. But partial weeks should be truncated to fit within the calendar year.

Comment: why not just use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to prevent the start and end days from going beyond your start/end variables?

Comment: What is your code producing? How is it incorrect?

Comment: for a particular range of date for eg.  2021-01-01  to 2021-12-31 i want start date of every week along with end date of every week but for the first week i need start day of week as  2021-01-01 and end date of week as 2021-12-31 if the above range is specified else i need a normal start date of week and end date of week.

Comment: what if your start/end dates are something else? Like 4/1/2022 - 6/30/2022?

Comment: @mamta does one of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you really only need to cover a full calendar year. The first two CTEs are just creating a "numbers table". You could plug in a replacement if necessary. I'm also assuming a `datefirst` setting of 7.

```
with d as (
    select n from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)) t(n)
), w as (
    select d0.n + d1.n * 8 as offset from d as d0 cross join d as d1
), weeks as (
    select
        offset + 1 as weeknum,
        dateadd(week, offset, basedate) as weekstart,
        dateadd(day, 6, dateadd(week, offset, basedate)) as weekend
    from w cross apply (
        select dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, @startdate), @startdate)
    ) as v(basedate)
)
select
    weeknum,
    case when weekstart < @startdate then @startdate else weekstart end,
    case when weekend   > @enddate   then @enddate   else weekend end
from weeks
where weekstart <= @enddate;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5f900ecd26b92e4a112f191730958cae

Comment: @Peter, good point. I put too many rows in the `d` expression. That causes some duplicates.

Comment: This is really close. The week start and end dates are off from what the OP wants. Otherwise this is a winner.

Comment: @Sean I think they match. Is it possibly your datefirst isn't 1?

Comment: Bwaaahaaaahaaaa!!!! Yeah was working on some funky stuff with my dummy database the other day. My datefirst was 7 LMAO!!! Further proof of why it is always important in a real environment to set that in your scripts. :D

Comment: I misread something in OP's script above. So OP does apparenyly use `datefirst` 7. I've adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like that, which will keep all the dates within the range specified. Hardcoding to a single year, which is almost over, is not good long term plan.

In Azure SQL, you can do this

```
declare @startdate date='2021-01-01'
declare @enddate date='2021-12-31'
declare @curdate date=@startdate
declare @week_end_date date

while(@curdate<=@enddate)
begin
    set @curdate= DATEADD(day,1-datepart(dw,@curdate),@curdate)
    select GREATEST(@startdate,@curdate) week_start_date

    set @week_end_date=dateadd(day,7-datepart(dw,@curdate),@curdate)
    select LEAST(@enddate,@week_end_date) week_end_date

    set @curdate= dateadd(week,1,@curdate)    
end
```

For SQL Server 2019, GREATEST/LEAST aren't available yet.

```
    declare @startdate date='2021-01-01'
    declare @enddate date='2021-12-31'
    declare @curdate date=@startdate
    declare @week_end_date date
    
    while(@curdate<=@enddate)
    begin
        set @curdate= DATEADD(day,1-datepart(dw,@curdate),@curdate)
        select IIF(@startdate>@curdate,@startdate,@curdate) week_start_date
    
        set @week_end_date=dateadd(day,7-datepart(dw,@curdate),@curdate)
        select IIF(@week_end_date > @enddate,@enddate, @week_end_date) week_end_date
    
        set @curdate= dateadd(week,1,@curdate)    
    end
```

Comment: i tried but i cant use least and greatest in sql server

Comment: This is MySql code but the question is clearly marked with sql server.

Comment: It's valid in Transact-SQL, but apparently only on Azure, sorry

Comment: Oh that is a new function in Azure, you are correct.

Comment: Not a fan of looping but this does return the right info.

Comment: this code will fail if i change end date from 2021-12-31 to 2022-12-31

Comment: depends on what you mean by fail....it will have one week in the middle that spans a year boundary, yes. But if your range is a two year range, that's more likely to be desired behavior

Comment: @mamta As I've commented on at least one of your other similar questions today, _get a calendar table_. Define these weeks exactly once, store them somewhere, and it will save everyone from having to pick away at all of your edge cases all day long.

Comment: @garr Godfrey that when a year changes and enter into next year it doesn't starts with 01-01